# Pasting code from Eclipse to Outlook has uninteligible highlighting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, eclipse, copy-paste

When copy/pasting code from Eclipse to Outlook I get a highlighting that makes code impossible to read in my emails. Consequently, I have either to give up the nice programming formatting or manually change the background color. In the image you see, from top to down : the code in Eclipse, the code in Eclipse after selection, and the code in Outlook after pasting (not selected).

[image: Color evolution]

How can I get by default a better result after pasting, e.g. keeping only the source formatting and font color, but no background color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with Eclipse *[since 2005](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86503)*.

The bug report does include a work around that may be of use to you:

> The problems seems to be related to the option "Highlight current
>   line".
>
> The bug does not reproduce if this option is turned off, or if you
>   select  several lines of text.

Comment: The "Highlight current line" option can be found in Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors